# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream.(node / nestjs) amazon Elastic

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs

Trying to deploy my first app (Back-end). But I meet an error of the type 502 Bad Gateway.

```
2022/04/16 09:40:14 [error] 4853#4853: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.123, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "172.31.12.175"
2022/04/16 09:40:16 [error] 4853#4853: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.6.213, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "172.31.12.175"
```

This is my main.ts file:-

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, () => {
    console.log(`⛱ Talent Zea Cloud listening on port ${PORT}`);
    console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

EB uses [port 8080 by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html) for node.js, but you are using port `8081`. So either change your port, or setup `PORT` env variable in EB to `8081`. From docs:

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk configures the proxy to forward requests to your **application on port 8080**.

Comment: I change my env and Elastic Beanstalk configuration into PORT 8081... But the results are the same.

Comment: @Zenixo That's good. So now check if it works.

Comment: The results are the same sir.

Comment: @Zenixo So change your port to 8080. Otherwise, it means that your application is simply not working. Please ensure that it works.

Comment: still The results are the same, sir. 

Comment: @Zenixo The you have to update your question with all the details of your EB setup, code that you use, testing procedure, and more.